# Sample code for storm-cassandra composite

Tags: cassandra, composite, apache-storm

I am looking for a sample code using storm-cassandra which writes to a cassandra column family having composite column. Though it claims this feature is available in 0.4.0 branch but there's no example.
BTW the project I am referring to is this https://github.com/hmsonline/storm-cassandra

Comment: There is, what looks to me to be, a detailed explanation of how to use the bolt on the linked project's readme. What are you looking for that is not already addressed there?

Comment: This issue's resolution is what I referred to  https://github.com/hmsonline/storm-cassandra/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

Below are the updates from the cassandra-storm co-author:

> I just pushed some internal changes and released 0.4.0-rc1. There
>   aren't composite examples in the "examples" directory (yet), but you
>   can find sample code in the unit tests.
>
> Specifically, look at the following classes:
>
> CompositeTest CompositeColumnTridentTupleMapper SimpleComposite I will
>   be updating the documentation and examples in the near future.

https://github.com/hmsonline/storm-cassandra/issues/23